# Toggle between two forms using Angular Animate module

Tags: angular, ng-animate, angular-animations

I want to display two forms.
1: Login Form
2. Register Form

First time show Login Form, on click of "create an account", I want to show Register Form and hind the Login Form and vice versa.
I did this using Jquery.

```
$('form').animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');
```

But I'm looking to do this using Angular animation module.

[image]

I'm using Angular 5.

**Sample:**

```
   <form class="login">
    <button (click)="toggleForm()">Create Account</button>
  </form>
  <form class="register">
    <button (click)="toggleForm()">Sign In</button>
  </form>

toggleForm() {
    $('form').animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' }, 'slow');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, not very beautiful or anything, but to point you into a direction you might go with toggeling your forms using angular animations: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i22e8r)

Comment: Thanks @Fussel. This is what exactly I'm looking for. Let me try and post the result.